# Doesn't take input inside finally block

Tags: java, finally

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    char c;
    do {    
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            int size=s.nextInt();
            int[] arr=new int[size];
                
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
                arr[i]=s.nextInt();
            }
                
            bubblesort(arr);
                
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
                
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Want to repeat(y/n)");
            System.out.println(s);
            c=s.next().charAt(0);
        }
    } while(c=='y' || c=='Y');
}
```

When I am giving valid input then after performing sorting it also takes input character c inside finally block, but when i give invalid input then after going to catch block it only prints the output inside finally block but doesn't take input character c. Why is it happening so?

Comment: Give an example of invalid input you type

Comment: *Don't* take input inside a `finally` block.

Comment: According to the code in your question, you are creating a new `Scanner` in every iteration of the `do ... while` loop. I don't think you need to do this. You only need to create it once, before the loop.

Comment: @doer Did my answer help you? Please don't leave answers without feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this happens because your scanner does not advance after receiving invalid input.
According to [official documentation of Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> ```
> public int nextInt(int radix)
> ```
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next
> token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below.
> If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input
> that matched.

And also:

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not
> pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved
> or skipped via some other method.

Therefore your scanner will never go past `nextInt` and reach the execution of `next()`